# Solving the ODE $xu'' + 2u' = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As stated in the title, I'm trying to solve this ODE. I know how to solve the ODE $xu'' + u' = (xu')' = 0$, but this trick doesn't work when we replace $u'$ with $2u'$. How can we find the general solution for this equation?

Comment: The function $u$, without derivatives, does not occur in your ODE.  Can we take $v = u'$?  In that case, we would get the ODE $v' + v / x = 0$, which considerably simplifies looking for the integrating factor.

Comment: reduce the order by putting $u'=y$

Comment: The solution is $u = a + b/x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same trick applies - but slightly modified.
$$
xu'' + u' + u' = \frac{d}{dx}\left[xu' + u\right] = 0
$$
so we have
$$
xu' + u = \lambda
$$
which you can solve by integration factor.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, solve it by integration factor? Let's say we make the equation a bit more general, e.g. $$xu' + (d-2)u = \lambda$$

Comment: Sorry I meant `integrating factor` have you come across solving first order linear differential equations? I assume you have, if not I can update the post.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you mean now. I think I got it.

Answer (score 0):

We can also put a new unknown function $z(x)=u'(x)$. With this substitution we arrive at the 1st order homoheneous linear equation $xz'+2z=0$.